# character string into a flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Hello I would like to know if there is a way to make a character string into a flutter widget?

For example in python we can use `eval("print('ok')")` which will be interpreted by the program

I would like to know if there is a similar thing in flutter / dart for widgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Dart it's bad practice to use this way.

But you can use it (yes syntax is awful):

```
import 'dart:isolate';

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final uri = Uri.dataFromString(
    '''
    void main() {
      print("ok");
    }
    ''',
    mimeType: 'application/dart',
  );
  await Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [], null);
}
```